# Upload file using jquery-ajax and path is in string

Tags: asp.net, json, jquery, c#-2.0

I am working on ASP.net 2.0 web application using C#.

I need to upload a file where path of the file is in string.

Methos in cs file

```
    [WebMethod]
    [ScriptMethod(ResponseFormat = ResponseFormat.Json)]
    public string SendContactUsEmail(string volume, ...., string strFileName, string message)
    {
    // Other parameter is removed in method and written ...
    // Need to upload file where path of the file is in string strFileName
    //rqContact.PakkagingfileName = $('#packagingFile').val(); = strFileName
    }
```

Value is passed from script.js is as below:

```
if(reqType == '5')                                    
{   
    rqContact.height = $('#height').val();  
    rqContact.PakkagingfileName = $('#packagingFile').val();
}

$.ajax({                            
    type: 'POST',                       
    url: $('#webServiceUrl').val() + "/SendContactUsEmail",
    contentType:"multipart/form-data; charset=utf-8",
    //contentType:"application/json; charset=utf-8",                        
dataType: 'json',                           
    data: JSON.stringify(rqContact),  
    error: function(){                       
       //alert("Error in Contact-us Ajax call");
      } ,

     success: function( response )
       {                            
         trckContactUsEvent()
         if (form.find( '.actionurl' ).attr('name') == 'actionurlcontactus'){
        Cufon.refresh('.cufon-text');

        $('.resultContainer p').html(response);
        $('.resultContainer').attr('data-status','success');
        $('.result').show();
        $('.result').modal({
            opacity:70,
            overlayCss: {backgroundColor:'#000000'},
            containerId: 'simplemodal-container4',
            containerCss: {height:'48px'}
        });
       }
}
});
```

Please advise how to upload the file.

Regards.

Answer (score 0):

You can use [Ajax Upload](http://www.asp.net/ajaxLibrary/AjaxControlToolkitSampleSite/AjaxFileUpload/AjaxFileUpload.aspx) to upload your file. You have to generate a .ashx(general handler) for your upload. you can send the path of the file to the handler and save the file to the path in the handler. this [Tutorial](http://aspsnippets.com/Articles/Implement-Uploadify-jQuery-Plugin-in-ASPNet.aspx) describes how to use Uploadify jquery plugin to upload files. I do not recommend you to use Uploadify but the tutorial can help you learn how to use General Handler.